# calculated Column in Datatable using Datatable-Expression

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable

I need a new column in my datatable which has a converted timestamp. My table looks like ..

```
BuildId unixTimeStamp BuildDate
1       1401286554000  -
2       1401286554000  -
3       1401286554000  -
```

the new column BuildDate needs to be computed using the below formula

```
dtDateTime.AddSeconds( unixTimeStamp ).ToLocalTime();
```

how can I achieve the same? Have been trying to do the same using

```
workTable.Columns["BuildDate"].Expression ="dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime()";
```

Get the below error

```
The expression contains undefined function call dtDateTime.AddSeconds().
```

Comment: Want to know how my expression should look like

Comment: workTable.Columns["BuildDate"].Expression  = ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
workTable.Columns["BuildDate"].Expression ="dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime()";
```

to

```
workTable.Columns["BuildDate"].Expression = "new DateTime(2010, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10).AddSeconds(double.Parse(unixTimeStamp)).ToLocalTime()";
```

I am assuming you are using hardcoded value for dtDateTime.
Also `unixTimeStamp` has to be `double`, it will blow up if its `string`, you can try to cast.

Comment: Guess you are close to the answer. I tried the below

Comment: new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime()".. get the error 'Missing operand after datetime operator'

Comment: `unixTimeStamp ` has to be double, it will blow up if its string, you can try to cast.

Comment: Changed the expression to new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(timestamp/1000).ToLocalTime() ..No luck. but when i try the same with a sample value of timestamp, it works fine

Comment: I have updated my answer. /100 does not auto-cast this is not javascript.

Comment: I updated this in code "new DateTime(2010, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10).AddSeconds(double.Parse(unixTimeStamp)).ToLocalTime()"; still get the same error. Tried this also "new DateTime(2010, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10).AddSeconds(double.Parse(unixTimeStamp)).ToLocalTime();  "; Still the same

Comment: Is there any other work around? I just want another column in my datatable with a readable date format , other than unix timestamp

Comment: Unless you are using if for direct databinding to UI you should be able to convert it after you read timestamp from datable. What error message are you getting this time? same old `Missing operand `?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55840/discussion-between-mhn-and-liufa).

Comment: From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx i don't think you can use DateTime funktions in DataColumn.Expression(). 
"DateTime can be coerced to and from String and itself only. "

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to use any DateTime-Function in the DataColumn.Expression. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
So I would not try it with a expression but with a loop

```
foreach (DataRow dr in workTable.Rows)
    dr["BuildDate"] = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1,0,0,0).AddSeconds(int.Parse(dr["unixTimeStamp"].ToString()));
```